# Alternatives to absolute error?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, data-mining, computational-statistics, functional-data-analysis

Let me explain my scenario in which I need to calculate absolute error.

Lets say the X is the actual value. And X' is the value of X with some error 'e'. So X' = X + e'.

Lets say i = 1 to 10000. I have X(i) as well as X'(i). Now I want to know (also want to plot on graph) that How much X' differs from X. One way to do is to calculate Absolute error and plot it on the graph.

I want to know if there are other ways to see how much X differs from X' besides absolute error? and Which one will be more appropriate in my case as I have to plot it as a graph? And also easier to follow for those who will see that plotted graph?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

If the values of X(i) vary over a wide range, then it may be appropriate to look at the relative differences

$e_{r}=\left| \frac{\left( X(i)-X'(i) \right)}{X(i)} \right| $.

Comment: It will be er(i) and how do I plot it.

Comment: @Brian What's the name of this error estimator?