# Alternative error estimator to the absolute difference

Tags: error

Are there alternatives to the `squared/absolute difference` used to estimate the error for a single individual relatively to the ground truth?

By `absolute difference`, I mean this formula:

$$error = |expectedValue - estimatedValue|$$

In my case, the error estimator is used as an objective function to assess individuals (generated stochastically), but the `absolute difference` gave me too many outliers in the error distribution. My goal is to find an error estimator that reduces this number of outliers.

**P.S:** I've already checked this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/106353), and the error estimator didn't give me a satisfying result.

Comment: The standard definition of error is different. (See tag).  What is absolute difference ?  To make a distinction between expected and estimated value is  difficult.

Comment: @subhashc.davar The absolute difference is the one given by the formula in the question.

Comment: Please  elaborate  expected and estimated value  in your field  and  how do you  locate or assess the outliers. This may help the users of this site  to respond your question.